# Oracle Creating Table using Data from Previous Tables with Calculations

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I currently have two tables, cts(time, symbol, open, close, high, low, volume) and dividends(time, symbol, dividend). i am attempting to make a third table named, dividend_percent with columns Time, Date and Percent. To get the percentage for the dividend I believe the formula to be ((close-(open+dividend))/open)*100.

The request however exceeded the size allowed by oraclexe and thus failed but i don't believe my request should have been that big.

`SQL> create table dividend_percent
  2  as (select c.Time, c.Symbol, (((c.close-(c.open+d.dividend))/c.open)*100) P
RCNT
  3  from cts c inner join dividend d
  4  on c.Symbol=d.Symbol);
from cts c inner join dividend d
     *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-12953: The request exceeds the maximum allowed database size of 11 GB`

Am i writing the query wrong or in such a way that's really inefficient? the two tables are big but i don't think too big.

Comment: You are only joining on Symbol, don't you want to narrow that down using date and/or time also?  Otherwise you are matching many to many.  Also, do you really want another table or just create a view with the fields you want?

Comment: yeah, that helped although now i am getting the error that on line 2 the divisor is equal to zero so I guess there is something wrong with my formula as well or the data.

Comment: See if there are records that exist with c.open = 0.  If so, you will have to handle that condition.

Comment: How much space do you have left before you hit the 11GB ceiling?  Look at `select sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 gb from dba_segments;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could make a view which combines the two tables and performs the necessary calculations when needed:

```
CREATE VIEW DIVIDEND_PERCENT_VIEW AS
  SELECT c.TIME,
         c.SYMBOL, 
         ((c.CLOSE - (c.OPEN + d.DIVIDEND)) / c.OPEN) * 100 AS PRCNT
    FROM CTS c
    INNER JOIN DIVIDEND d
      ON c.SYMBOL = d.SYMBOL AND
         c.TIME = d.TIME
    WHERE c.OPEN <> 0;
```

This would avoid duplicating the data, eliminate the need to store everything twice, and perform the `PRCNT` calculation for data added after the view is created as well as for pre-existing data.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use `materialized view` if you are intending to perform DML operations as well as keep the table in sync.